# Viewing files other than ones located in ubuntu partition

Tags: 12.10

I recently started trying using Ubuntu 12.10 desktop from a USB stick. Is there any way that I could view and use my files in other partition, which I now only do while booting in with Windows 7 Ultimate (32 bit) version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view all available disk partitions in `nautilus` which is default file browser in Ubuntu. Just open nautilus from sidebar or dash and in left pane you'll see all the partitions listed on top.